# Нужно ли удалять динамически созданные объекты после завершения программы C++?

Tags: c++, память, delete, выделение-памяти, new

Хотел узнать - всегда ли компилятор/ОС очищает память, выданную из кучи с помощью оператора new, после исполнения программы, или же это нужно сделать вручную с помощью операторов delete?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Компилятор не удаляет сам (не добавляет вызовов деструктора в код) для объектов, которые созданы просто через new. Да, в 99% случаев память будет возвращена системе, но деструкторы вызваны не будут. Если на это закладывается какая то логика, то ой-ой.

Крайне желательно явно освобождать все, что было выделено явно через new/malloc. Если объект выделяет какие то особые ресурсы операционной системы, то она может не освобождать их. А вот файловые дескрипторы будут закрыты ОС. Но вот если это ostream, то нет никаких гарантий, что его внутренние буфера будут сброшены перед закрытием файлового дескриптора и могут быть утеряны данные.

Comment: "особые ресурсы операционной системы" - у вас есть какой-то пример таких ресурсов?

Comment: Например, семафоры https://stackoverflow.com/q/34756406/644688

Comment: Ну, семафоры в каком-то смысле ближе к файлам, чем к выделенной памяти. Ведь никого не удивляет, что одна программа создает файл, а другие используют его после завершения создателя

Comment: ну в линуксе (юниксе) почти все файлы (даже файлы:) ). Но вот если файл можно закрыть, то с семафором там все сильно сильно нетривиально. Оно выглядит просто, пока не столкнёшься с этим всем.

Answer (score 1):

Всё надо аккуратно освобождать. Да, система освободит память, когда потеряет записи о том, что она была выделена. Но это просто манипуляции с дескрипторами страниц, при этом не вызываются деструкторы и не выполняются никакие действия, которые должны были быть выполнены самой софтиной при освобождении памяти. Просто забыли, что память была выделена, из-за чего снова можем её выделять. И не более того. Вы точно знаете, что экзел не из-за этого при своём штатном закрытии просит сообщить о своём падении в мелкософт? Разводить глюки – плохая идея, разводить призраки глюков – идея ещё хуже. Одно дело закрывать дебажную версию софтины в середине теста, не дожидаясь аккуратного освобождения, или не доходить до освобождения из-за глюков, а совсем другое – бросать указатели без присмотра и ждать, что система подотрёт Вам нос. Она-то подотрёт, разведя сопли уже у пользователя, чьи знания Вашего кода заведомо меньше Ваших. Мало ли какие записи в файлы, в ключи реестра, в разделяемую память... были запланированы в деструкторах? В том числе, в Ваших собственных. Система, даже если сбросит буфера, об этих записях не догадается всё равно. И носы программистам система подтирает только для того, чтоб память не текла при выходе на три кнопки и при тестировании в процессе разработки. А не для того, чтоб на аварийное освобождение полагались в релизе.

Comment: В том числе и из-за таких деструкторов  следует считать C++ одной из величайших ошибок человечества

Comment: Наоборот. Вот представьте: некий класс А имеет член l, который сам является объектом некоторого класса и ведёт свой локальный xml-лог. При удалении любого экземпляра класса A член l должен аккуратно закрыть все теги. Но во время существования l в буферах нет закрывающих тегов. Я зык c++ предоставляет ВОЗМОЖНОСТЬ аккуратно прописать закрытие такого лога в деструкторе класса, чьим экезмпляром является l. Но тут приходите Вы и объявляете её выличайшей ошибкой. Самому не смешно?

Comment: Тот же пример. Некий класс А имеет член l, который сам является объектом некоторого класса и ведёт свой локальный xml-лог. При удалении любого экземпляра класса A член l должен аккуратно закрыть все теги. Но во время существования l в буферах нет закрывающих тегов. Но экземпляр класса A создан динамически по указателю pa. Пока всё в порядке. Но вот пришёл llollcat и не написал delete pa. При закрытии программы память по pa освободилась, теперь её можно выдать другой программе, но деструктор отработать не может в принципе. И никакой сборщик мусора ему не поможет. Лог не закрыт.

Comment: *`"Но вот пришёл llollcat и не написал delete pa."`*. Так и я говорю именно об этом, о мэрфологии, обезьяне с гранатой и языке, который провоцирует ее

Comment: Если Вы забыли вернуться домой, то это проблема не двери.

Answer (score 0):

> всегда ли компилятор/ОС очищает память

Да. Возможно на каких-то древних ОС это не так, но я с такими не сталкивался.

> или же это нужно сделать вручную

Нет.